# SWF flash not appearing

Tags: html, flash, swfobject

My code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("wpimages/slideshowpro.swf", "ssp_pg_2", "506", "299", "9.0.0", false, { paramXMLPath: "wpimages/34e1b044450b358.xml" }, {"allowFullScreen":"true","menu":"true","wmode":"transparent"}, {});</script>
  <div id="pg_2" style="position:absolute;left:25px;top:678px;width:506px;height:299px;"><div id="ssp_pg_2"></div></div>
```

For some reason my flash wont load and comes up with video file not found.

Comment: Did you get any error in console ?

Comment: There is swf file in proper path? `wpimages/slideshowpro.swf` ?

Comment: yes the file is there and no errors.

Comment: How are you loading SlideShowPro? Is it a local thing or a part of an online service? According to [SlideShowPro's website](http://slideshowpro.net/): "All SlideShowPro products and services have been terminated as of December 1, 2015."

Comment: Does it actually say "video not found?" If yes, your Flash is loading fine but the video is not available.